# Android:How to draw in View section where options are outside the view tag in same XML l

Tags: android, view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/test"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_show"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:text="circle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="line" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_show"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

i want to draw(circle/line) in view section after pressing the circle or line button in same activity extended class . and also the circle will be Drawn by expanding or resizing by dragging

Comment: Could you be specific about you question? Question is a bit unclear.

Comment: after click the circle button i want to draw a circle in the view section in the xml which is given . like the ms paint software where drawing option are outside the view section  and the canvas is in the view section  . hope its clear now